# Docker build for React App failing in Gitlab CI runner

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab-ci, create-react-app

I have been trying to create a react app `Gitlab CI` but it keeps failing on the `RUN npm run build` (tried `RUN CI=true npm run build` too) when trying to create a docker file.

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.1

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app/

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm -g install serve

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /app/

RUN ls /app/

#Build react/vue/angular bundle static files
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5000
# serve build folder on port 5000
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-p", "5000"]
```

fails at step `RUN npm run build` with the following error:

```
Step 8/10 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in d4b3bc5de229

> payed-fe@0.1.0 build /app
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Cannot find file './app' in './src'.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! payed-fe@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the payed-fe@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-20T15_52_14_979Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

However on my local machine everything works like a charm (npm start, npm run build, even same Dockerfile on my local builds successfully).
Thanks in Advance!

--- EDIT 1 ---
yes `ls` gives the same output on my local system and CI. 
`./src/index.js` is just my entry file. Here are the contents:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./app";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And yes the paths are perfectly alright as it is running successfully on my local machine.

--- EDIT 2 ---

Output of `/root/.npm/_logs/*.log` after I changed the working dir to `/payed` - Still no luck!

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~prebuild: payed-fe@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: payed-fe@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/payed/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: CWD: /payed
10 silly lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle payed-fe@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: payed-fe@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid payed-fe@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /payed
16 verbose Linux 4.14.48-coreos-r2
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.11.1
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error payed-fe@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the payed-fe@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Does `RUN ls /app/` return the same result on your host and on CI environment? Do you have additional info in `2018-12-20T15_52_14_979Z-debug.log`? What is `./src/index.js`?

Comment: Added all the info you asked for in the question itself. Thanks. And sorry I have no clue how to access `2018-12-20T15_52_14_979Z-debug.log` from Gitlab CI shared Runner.

Comment: The line `import App from "./app";` seems guilty here. Have you an `app` inside the current working directory (`/app`)? By the way, you can get debug log as it is inside the container : `RUN npm run build || cat /root/.npm/_logs/*.log`.

Comment: thanks let me try renaming my working directory to something else and try printing the debug log as well. will post here in c ase I find something interesting.

Comment: No luck. Added the output as `Edit 2`

Comment: Heck :( Can't see what's wrong here if `docker build` succeeds on your machine and if the build context is identical. Do you run `docker build` with `--no-cache` locally? What command is run on Gitlab CI? Maybe you should also add `node` and `npm` tags to your question, people with more expertise in `node` may have faced the same issue.

Comment: Yes `--no-cache` also passes succesfully on local. Sure I'll add more tags. Thanks :)

Comment: @KaranGujral hey, I have the same issue right now. Have you figured out what was the problem here?

Comment: @webdevbyjoss I renamed my app file to entry file and it somehow worked (Be careful of the case-senstivity while creating files/folders). I still don't know what the problem was. Hope you solve it soon too!

Comment: @webdevbyjoss like KaranGujral pointed out, be careful with case-sensitivity. That was exactly the issue I was facing... a folder being imported using the wrong case (lower vs camelCase). MacOS filesystem is case-insensitive so it would work fine locally, but Linux most common file systems are case-sensitive.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try CI=false

CI=true is the default...

Comment: Setting CI=false seems counter-intuitive, but it seems to work for me. When I set CI=true, the build fails, but when I set it to CI=false, it works... I'm not using containers at this time though.